# PARSE XML IN PHP

Tags: php, parsing

HI , all ..

I need to parse an DWF file using PHP, which looks like an xml file . 
example :

```
    <dwf:Feature id="BXV1D8mWfkGOqXbyoIxQ2g">
 <dwf:Properties id="hZBTdWkXKEuhGWAeTpMOUA">
  <dwf:Property name="NO" value="0" /> 
  <dwf:Property name="DESCRIPTION" value="Testing" /> 
  <dwf:Property name="DATE" value="06/25/09" /> 
  <dwf:Property name="BY" value="SJ" /> 
  <dwf:Property name="CHK" value="JF" /> 
  </dwf:Properties>
```

How to parse this.. I am new to PHP xml parsing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simplexml, like so: http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

Would be nice if you provided the xml prolog as well. The `children` method accepts a namespace prefix if you need to use that.

Comment: Thanks meder, i have used simplexml but the format here is different its not like  <title>My Title</title>  its like <title value="sds" /> so how do I get value of this sds ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/DOMDocument). To deal with namespaces (which you have) take a look at the methods that end in `NS`.

An alternative is [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml). The `SimpleXMLElement::children` methods accepts a namespace or namespace prefix.

Comment: Thanks Artefacto, Any examples plz

Comment: @ravi See the manual, there are examples there (the linked pages include even a link that says "examples").