# to post only a specific thing from a text in php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

Hey guy's I have a SOAP call that returns something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"
     encoding="utf-8"?><item> <dailystats>
     <date>2011-03-18</date>
     <impressions>17</impressions>
     <clicks>1</clicks> <leads>1</leads>
     <num_sales>0</num_sales> <sales>
     0.00</sales> <sub_sales> 0.00</sub_sales> <commission> 1.10</commission> click_thru_ratio>5.88%</click_thru_ratio>
     </dailystats> </item>
```

Now I want to make a script that posts this in a readable format.
For example I want it to look like this:

Clicks: ( then here it searches in the code above for the ammount of clicks and posts them here ).

Is this possible and could anyone help me out?

Comment: You're looking for a [PHP Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php). Possible Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630866/php-parse-xml-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659369/parse-big-xml-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582592/php-how-to-parse-this-xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372692/parse-xml-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706042/how-to-parse-xml-file-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can display your XML document with xslt

See : http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Transforming-XML-with-XSLT-and-PHP/3/

Always think template when you want to display data, and xslt is a perfect template engine.